# Verify paypal payment using C#

Tags: c#, .net, curl, paypal, integration

I'm quite new to PayPal integration.

Currently I'm working on a mobile app that allows me to make payment to my merchant. However, after making a payment using the app, the transaction is reflected as "pending". I've read in some places I am required to verify the payment.

I've don't quite understand how it works, because I need to write it in C# however most of the documentation requires me to do a cURL command.

Any place or documentation that allows me to get started with the verification of payment?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

PayPal has an officially supported .NET sdk for anything you need to do server side. Here are [samples](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/tree/master/Samples/Source)

Answer (score 0):

I use the IPN (Instant Payment Notification) from Paypal and used [this site](http://blog.artemlos.net/posts/a-simple-way-to-integrate-paypal-into-asp-net-mvc-4/) as a base for my code. The PayPal developer site has plenty of tips, you just have to apply the logic C#, where there isn't a code example.

Another Controller is available on https://mvcsamples.svn.codeplex.com/svn/trunk/Kona.Web/Controllers/PayPalController.cs