# How to verify paypal payment if its authentic or not C#

Tags: c#, paypal, sandbox

I want to verify user payment whether its authentic or not. I am getting response from pay pal but i want to resend that response to pay pal to verify it. I am getting all the details regarding payments and user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to verify successful payment of paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274449/how-to-verify-successful-payment-of-paypal)

Comment: Another better duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28810202/verify-paypal-payment-using-c-sharp

Comment: I didn't get any help from mention links. can you please any sample code to send my token id buyer details to that api to just verify whether payment is authentic or not ?

Comment: @FrankerZ .....

Answer (score 0):

You can verify your by using pay pal api.

First install payPal from nuget packages

```
Install-Package PayPal
```

Secondly configure your webconfig like this.

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="paypal" type="PayPal.SDKConfigHandler, PayPal" />
 </configSections>

<configuration>
<paypal>
    <settings>
      <add name="mode" value="sandbox"/>
      <add name="clientId" value="client_id"/>
      <add name="clientSecret" value="client_secret_id"/>
    </settings>
  </paypal>
</configuration>
```

Then from server side i mean C# end you can verify your payment like this.

```
                var config = ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties();
                var accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(config).GetAccessToken();
                var apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);
                // --verify payment ---
                var payment = Payment.Get(apiContext, "PAY-YourCheckNo");
```

Here payment variable will populate with different status defending upon your pay-yourcheckNo. This is how you can verify your payment done through paypal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. let me try

Comment: Do you literally need to prepend "PAY-"? Which is the "YourCheckNo"? I've tried both the order id as well as the payment id (found in payments.captures), but no luck.

Comment: Yes you have to prepend PAY with your checkNo then it will return the payment information but this thing was years later I don't think so it will work like this may be they have made some changes